# How can I speed up this "for" loop?

Tags: python, laravel, loops, ssh

I have written a small piece of code in Python where I am getting data from server for N elements in the array.  I am passin data from Laravel controller to python. Here is my python code:

```
import requests
import sys
import json

def jsontoarray(json_data):
  result = list()
  data= json.loads(json_data)
  for d in data:
    response = requests.get('myUrl/readData?name=' + d)
    result.append(response.content)
    print(result)
jsontoarray(sys.argv[1])
```

And my Laravel controller:

```
public function data(Request $request){
  $process = new Process(['python', $scriptPath, json_encode($request->data)]);
  $process->run();
  $process->getOutput();
}
```

However, this is too slow when having large amount of elements in the array over which I am looping. How can I speed it up?

Comment: multi-threading is one option, have you looked into that yet?

Comment: you are doing sending 1 argument per GET requests, is there any way to send multiple? Maybe `myUrl/readData?names=bob,karen,lia,john`

Comment: My guess is that slowness is due to fetching content via requests. So you could aggressively cache the content or use multiprocessing + async instead of a synchronous loop.

Comment: you have two options, you can use multiprocessing, but that would have to happen within the Laravel controller, or you can use multi-threading or async inside the Python process to get around the I/O bottleneck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As martineau said, you can use threading to speed up your program. Just import the "threading" library and add threding.Thread in your class's parentheses and name your function "def run(self):" then put whatever you like your thread to do inside that function and wherever you want to start your thread use your object name and then ".start()" this way it will start your thread. Most of the times it is not a good idea to do this but if you have to then you should do it. By the way if your program is more I/O (input and output) bound then it is better to use threads, if it is CPU bound it should be better for you to use multi-processing. You can also watch these tutorials for better understanding:

Threading tutorials:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WaXK8G1hb_Q

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEEhzQoKtQU

Multi-processing:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso

I hope this has helped you!